# Why are unused parameters not discarded by the compiler?

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization

I've played a little with the Compiler Explorer (Godbolt) and noticed something which I cannot explain.

Lets so suppose we have a function

```
int answer(){
    return 42;
}
```

The assembly looks like this (Clang 9, but other compilers behave similar):

```
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    mov     eax, 42 
    pop     rbp
    ret
```

Which is rather reasonable. Now if we intorduce a UNUSED parameter to the function like:

```
int answer( double d ){ // or even without name
    return 42;
}
```

the assembly changes to:

```
push    rbp
mov     rbp, rsp
movsd   qword ptr [rbp - 8], xmm0
mov     eax, 42
pop     rbp
ret
```

My question is why doesn't the compiler omit the moving of the double, because it is clearly unused (and the compiler knows about this because it provides are warning for this). Whats the reasoning behind this?

Comment: Did you compile it with optimization? (`-O2` flag)

Comment: As seen [here](https://godbolt.org/z/vFrO15) there can be quite a difference between unoptimized and optimized builds.

Comment: I checked it on godbolt, it get's optimized out with -O2 on clang 7.0.0

Comment: Actually, @churill, `-O1` seems to be enough to do it.

Comment: Thanks guys. Yes I totally not payed attention to the optimization flags, duh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you type `-O1` into the compiler options box, you'll see the optimised result:

```
mov  eax, 42
ret
```

You can see that nothing's done with the parameter in that version. In addition, no stack frame is created or torn down, just a simple "load up the retutn value and exit".

There's little reason to perform optimisation unless specified by the user (even if that specification is because of some default optimisation level that your environment may have).

Answer (score 3):

> My question is why doesn't the compiler omit the moving of the double, because it is clearly unused

Because this is an optimization, and you didn't tell the compiler to optimize.

There's actually a good reason for *not* optimizing this kind of thing in general except when asked: it's much easier to debug a non-optimized build like this, because parameters, local variables and stack frames are all laid out in a standard way.

When you try running an optimized build through a debugger, you'll see that, for example, it *might* be unable to show you the value of the double argument inside the function: even if it isn't used, you may want to see how the function was called (the fine details of what the debugger is able to show about optimized code will depend on the compiler, version and options, but that's the general idea).

Comment: Ah, the hours I'll never get back, instruction-stepping through disassembled release builds ...